# Jquery Ajax json Serializable

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am learing using jquery ajax to hander the JSON..i writre a demo code.
HTMLCODE

```
$(function () {
            $("#add").click(function () {
                var json = '{ "str":[{"Role_ID":"2","Customer_ID":"155","Brands":"Chloe;","Country_ID":"96;"}]}';
                $.ajax({

                    url: "func.aspx/GetJson",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: json, 

                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });

 <div>
       <input type="button" value="add" id="add" />
    </div>
```

i got a input and bind a script function to it, now the proble is comeing..
my C# functiong like that.

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetJson(object str)
        {
            return str.ToString();//good for work


        }
        [Serializable]
        public class TestClass
        {
            public TestClass()
            {
            }

            public TestClass(string role_id, string customer_id, string brands, string countryid)
            {
                this.Role_ID = role_id;
                this.Customer_ID = customer_id;
                this.Brands = brands;
                this.Country_ID = countryid;
            }

            public string Role_ID { get; set; }
            public string Customer_ID { get; set; }
            public string Brands { get; set; }
            public string Country_ID { get; set; }
        }
```

when i user 
public static string GetJson(object str)
everything is so good.~~ no error at all
but . when i try to use my own class TestClass.
firebug tell me that
"Type 'TestClass' is not supported for deserialization of an array."
.any body can give me help:XD

Answer (score 0):

This is how it looks when I do this using a WCF webservice. Hopefully it can help you. Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Script:

```
var data = {
        emailAddress: emailAddress,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        groups: groups
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Client.svc/Subscribe",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processdata: true,
        success: function (result) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Service:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint]
public class Client : IClient
{
    public bool Subscribe(string emailAddress, string firstName, string lastName, string[] groups)
    {
        //do something
        return true;
    }
}
```